# OnsenUI: combine tabbar, slide menu and dialogs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, onsen-ui

`enter code here`
Sample here: http://ws.8balls.tk/test/ 
CodePen: http://codepen.io/steven7979/pen/NGKpMq

Normal process:
Step 1: click "View Detail" button
Step 2: click "Enter Content" link
Step 3: input any text and press "OK" link
=> The text was bound into current view

My trouble: 
Step 1: repeat "normal process"
Step 2: click on all tabbar item to view content
Step 3: repeat "normal process"
=> The text was NOT bound into current view

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 0):

I updated new version and this issue was solved. https://onsen.io/download.html#download-templates